# Getting value of checkbox when using json and $_GET

Tags: php, json

I am having trouble getting hold of which checkbox has been selected when using JSON.

This is my HTML

```
<form id="patronReg" action="" method="get" onsubmit="jsquicksub(this); return false;">
        <input type="checkbox" name="__gold" value="gold" id="patron-gold"/><strong>Gold patrons </strong>$3,000 (+GST for businesses)<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="__silver" value="silver" id="patron-silver" /><strong>Silver patrons </strong>$1,500 (+GST for businesses)<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="__families" value="families" id="patron-families" /><strong>Families and individual </strong>$500<br />
```

My JSON javascript file looks like this

```
function jsquicksub(po_form) {

if (gb_ajaxbusy)
    return false;

gb_ajaxbusy = true;


var lo_request = {};
lo_request.g = $(po_form).find('#patron-gold').val();
lo_request.s = $(po_form).find('#patron-silver').val();
lo_request.f = $(po_form).find('#patron-families').val();


$(po_form).fadeTo(200, 0.3);

$.getJSON('/patron-form-process', lo_request, function(po_result) {

    gb_ajaxbusy = false;
    $(po_form).fadeTo(0, 1);

    if (!po_result.success) {
        $('#errorReport').show();
        document.getElementById('errorReport').innerHTML = po_result.content;
        //alert(po_result.content);
        return false;
    }else{
        setTimeout(function() { 
                $.modal.close();
        }, 2500);
    }
    // replace form with thankyou message
    $(po_form).replaceWith(po_result.content);
    // empty errrReport element
    $('#errorReport').hide();

}); }
```

And my php form processing file is this

```
// function gets passed values after validation and returns a message to the user on screen
function jsonreturn($pb_success, $ps_content = null) {

$lo_result = (object) array('success'=>$pb_success, 'content'=>$ps_content);

ob_clean();
echo json_encode($lo_result);
exit;

} // end jsonreturn()
// membership type

$ps_gold = isset($_GET['g'])? $_GET['g']: null;
$ps_families = isset($_GET['f'])? $_GET['f']: null;
$ps_families = isset($_GET['f'])? $_GET['f']: null;

if ($ps_gold == 'gold') {
    $ps_membership = 'Gold patron';
}
elseif ($ps_silver == 'silver') {
    $ps_membership = 'Silver patron';
}
elseif ($ps_families == 'families') {
    $ps_membership = 'Families and individual';
}
else {
    $ps_membership = '';
}
```

So my question is, how to I get the selected checkbox value to the php file, when it goes from the form to the javascript file then to php. It is probably a very stupid question! But I am very new to JSON. Once I get to the php file, I am using phpmailer to send all values from my form in an email. It is working great! Except for the checkbox part!

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to handle this would be to use the [Jquery Checked Selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) to pass which checkboxes have been selected. For example:

```
// ...
var lo_request = {};
lo_request.g = $(po_form).find('#patron-gold').is(':checked');
lo_request.s = $(po_form).find('#patron-silver').is(':checked');
lo_request.f = $(po_form).find('#patron-families').is(':checked');

$.getJSON('/patron-form-process', lo_request, function(po_result) {
// ...
```

Then from the PHP side:

```
$ps_gold = isset($_GET['g'])? $_GET['g'] === 'true' : false;
$ps_silver = isset($_GET['s'])? $_GET['s'] === 'true' : false;
$ps_families = isset($_GET['f'])? $_GET['f'] === 'true' : false;

if ($ps_gold) {
    $ps_membership = 'Gold patron';
}
elseif ($ps_silver) {
    $ps_membership = 'Silver patron';
}
elseif ($ps_families) {
    $ps_membership = 'Families and individual';
}
else {
    $ps_membership = '';
}
```

However, I will point out that it seems that the logic for deciding `$ps_membership` seems to lend itself more towards radio buttons than checkboxes, since each option is mutually exclusive. With that said, the solution above should do what you need.

Comment: Thanks so much! This is what I was missing! I think my designer is after radio buttons that look like a checkbox though. Can I change the appearance of them to be square? I know this solution isnt perfect yet, I just wanted to get this part working then sort out checkbox looking radio buttons! Thanks so much for your help!!